# Find a minimal value in each array in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following data in Python 3.3:

```
my_array = 
   [{'man_id': 1, '_id': ObjectId('1234566'), 'type': 'worker', 'value': 11}, 
   {'man_id': 1, '_id': ObjectId('1234577'), 'type': 'worker', 'value': 12}],

   [{'man_id': 2, '_id': ObjectId('1234588'), 'type': 'worker', 'value': 11}, 
    {'man_id': 2, '_id': ObjectId('3243'), 'type': 'worker', 'value': 7},
    {'man_id': 2, '_id': ObjectId('54'), 'type': 'worker', 'value': 99},
    {'man_id': 2, '_id': ObjectId('9879878'), 'type': 'worker', 'value': 135}],
   #.............................
   [{'man_id': 13, '_id': ObjectId('111'), 'type': 'worker', 'value': 1}, 
    {'man_id': 13, '_id': ObjectId('222'), 'type': 'worker', 'value': 2},
    {'man_id': 13, '_id': ObjectId('3333'), 'type': 'worker', 'value': 9}]
```

There are 3 arrays. How do I find  an element in each array with minimal value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[min(arr, key=lambda s:s['value']) for arr in my_array]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that is acc for you:

```
for arr in my_array:
   minVal = min([row['value'] for row in arr])
   print [row for row in arr if row['value'] == minVal]
```