# Find maximum value in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, data-structures

Given a data structure:

```
   [
    {'id':0, 'items': 
      [
       {'id': 0,  name: "Tom1", age: 10}, 
       {'id': 0, name: "Mark1", age: 15}, 
       {'id': 0, name: "Pam1", age: 17}
      ]
    },
    {'id':1, 'items': 
      [
       {'id': 1,  name: "Tom12", age: 8}, 
       {'id': 1, name: "Mark12", age: 3}, 
       {'id': 1, name: "Pam12", age: 2}
      ]
    },

    {'id':2, 'items': 
      [
       {'id': 2,  name: "Tom13", age: 55}, 
       {'id': 2, name: "Mark13", age: 66}, 
       {'id': 2, name: "Pam13", age: 77}
      ]
    },
  ]
```

I want to find an item in each dictionary where age has maximum value and select it. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Oddly reminiscient of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262066/find-a-minimal-value-in-each-array-in-python) from today, though not a duplicate.

Comment: Looks like JSON data. You know you could load it directly with `json`, right?

Comment: Really? How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
for dVals in yourData:
    print max(dVals['items'], key=lambda x:x['age'])
```

Or one-liner:

```
print [max(dVals['items'], key=lambda x: x['age']) for dVals in yourData]

{'id': 0, 'age': 17, 'name': 'Pam1'}
{'id': 1, 'age': 8, 'name': 'Tom12'}
{'id': 2, 'age': 77, 'name': 'Pam13'}
```

Comment: Perhaps even more readable from the operator module: `print max(dVals['items'], key=operator.itemgetter('age'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_largest_age(entry):
  return max(entry['items'], key=lambda d: d['age'])

map(find_largest_age, data_structure)
```

`map` will apply the function to each entry in your toplevel list.

`max` will call the function provided in `key` on each member of the `'items'` list and return the one for which that function gives a maximal value.

Note that you can make this a one-liner:

```
map(lambda e: max(e['items'], key=lambda d: d['age']), data_structure)
```

But that's rather more unreadable.